# How can I solve this using prime factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm stuck with this problem: $2^x \cdot 3^3 \cdot 26^y = 39^z$ for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know that there isn't a natural solution for the equation, but I need to "prove" it using prime factors. I'm stuck here:

$$
2^x \cdot 3^3 \cdot (2\cdot 13)^y = (3\cdot 13)^z \\
\implies 2^x \cdot 3^3 \cdot 2^y \cdot 13^y = 3^z \cdot 13^z \\
\implies 2^{x+y} \cdot 3^3 \cdot 13^y = 3^z \cdot 13^z
$$

Could anyone give me a hint on this problem? (Sorry for the formatting)

Comment: Well, the left side is even and the right side is not.... Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) for formatting.

Comment: There is only one integer solution: $z=3,y=3,x=-3$.

Comment: @T.Bongers: If $x=y=0$ then the left size is odd (and whether or not $0\in\mathbb{N}$ is subjected to terminology).

Comment: Well, then clearly x+y=0;z=3; and z=y.  Is that possible for natural numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "natural solutions" means positive integers:

$2 \times 27 \times 26 = 702 = 2^2 \times 3^3 \times 13$ while $39 = 3 \times 13$. Therefore $x = y = z = 1$ is not a solution. In fact, no solution will work because the prime factorization of $2^x 3^3 26^y$ will always have that pesky oddly even prime while the factorization of $39^z$ will not, specifically, as $2^{x + y}$ as you have already figured.

Try seeing $39^z$ as $2^0 \times 3^z \times 13^z$. But since $x, y$ are positive integers, $x + y > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$2^x \cdot 3^3 \cdot 26^y = 39^z\iff 2^{x+y}\cdot3^3\cdot13^y=3^z\cdot13^z\Rightarrow2^{x+y}=3^{z-3}\cdot13^{z-y}$

This is possible just when you have $1=1\cdot1$ i. e. $x+y=z-3=z-y=0$. Thus $$(x,y,z)=(-3,3,3)$$